# Custom color scheme in Windows Phone 8 map control

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

I am creating an app which mainly features a map and some special features. Because the map is the place where 90% of the interaction happens, I consider it as an important part of the app. Having watched Dave Crawford's design consultations, an essential part of making an app look good is to create a brand. Because there is pretty much nothing except the app bar, the map and some markers, I'm considering coloring the map itself.
But I've got two questions:

- Will this have an positive affect on both the branding and the usability? I don't want the user to get a headache just because I prefer my color scheme, but I want my app to be unique
- Will this be possible when using the phone built-in map control? This seems especially important to me as Windows Phone is capable of saving maps ofline and I want to have access to these maps

Comment: I would suggest hunting down a UI Master like Travis Lowdermilk or possibly even pinging DVLUP on twitter.

Comment: That would answer the first question (and I'll probably do that), but the second one is something that surely fits stackoverflow best becuase of the massive power of its users.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by the "Built in Map Control" do you mean Nokia HERE Maps app? If so then no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that should not adjust something like a map, for branding experiences.

Users have strict mental models of how maps should look and function. Deviating from the norm, only for brand, is not wise.

You might consider other ways to introduce your brand and value.

Perhaps through unique pins and markers, splash screens, additive menus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the styling of the map itself (roads, parks, etc.)?

You would need to use your own custom map tiles, perhaps produced using a service such as [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/).

I use my own custom map tiles in [NZ Topo Map](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/store/app/nz-topo-map-beta/b861ab51-a68d-456f-9ae4-cbed66736b36), but I had to fallback to the older WP7 map control (Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map) in order to use them. I couldn't find a way to base the map purely on my own tiles using the WP8 map control unfortunately ([this answer has more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16888468/250254)).